# scrollToLocation to top for sectionList scrolls past top item

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-sectionlist

ScrollToLocation to top for sectionList scrolls to blank page that past very top items.

I just want to scroll to very top items, but it scrolls to blank page over the top items

I used few different things

1)

```
this.sectionListRef.scrollToLocation({ sectionIndex: 0, itemIndex: 0 })
```

2)

```
this.sectionListRef.scrollToLocation({ sectionIndex: 0, itemIndex: -1 })
```

3)

```
this.sectionListRef.scrollToLocation({ sectionIndex: 0, itemIndex: 0, viewOffset: 200 })
```